# Branch of $m$th root of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, radicals

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the open subset $G$
of $C$. Let the point $z_0$ of $G$ be a zero of $f$ of order $m$. I want to prove that there is a branch of $f^{1/m}$ in some open disk centered at $z_0$.

I tried to prove this way but I am not sure about my solution:

Since $z_0$ is a zero of $f$ of order $m$, there exist an analytic function $g$ s.t. $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mg(z)$; $g(z_0)\neq0$. If there is a branch $h$ of log$f$, then $e^{h/m}$ is a branch of $f^{1/m}$. My problem is how to prove such $h$ exists becuase $f(z_0)=0$.

I appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because *every* analytic function $g$ without zeros defined on an open disk $D(z_0.r)$ has some analytic logarithm; just take a primitive $G$ of $\dfrac{g'}g$ such that $\exp\bigl(G(z_0)\bigr)=g(z_0)$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That is true. Now, what about $(z-z_0)^m$ which is zero at $z_0$ and then log(f) does not exist. Does $D(z_0,r)$ excludes 0?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I wrote about the function $g$, which has no zeros, not about $f$.

Comment: I meant, as you said $g$ has a branch of log. Does it imply that $f$ also has?

Comment: No, since, as you wrote, $f(z_0)=0$.

Comment: That is true. So how can we deduce that there is a branch of $f^{1/m}$ from the fact that there is a branch of log $g$?

Comment: Because then you consider the function $(z-z_0)e^{G(z)/m}$. Clearly,$$\left((z-z_0)e^{G(z)/m}\right)^m=(z-z_0)^me^{G(z)}=(z-z_0)^mg(z)=f(z).$$